# 301 redirect — WordPress — help identify hack in htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, redirect

My WordPress site is redirecting visitors from home page and killing my load speed.

After visiting the redirected site I'm unable to enter my own site unless I visit via cpanel.

After a Google search, it was suggested that I should check the htaccess file; I'm unsure what to look for — could someone assist?

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>
# Expires Caching Start #
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
# Expires Caching End #
# BEGIN WPSuperCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#If you serve pages from behind a proxy you may want to change 'RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on' to something more sensible
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html.gz" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html.gz" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index-https.html" [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/supercache/%{SERVER_NAME}/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>

# END WPSuperCache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# Do not write anything between "GZip Ninja Speed -- Starts" and "GZip Ninja Speed -- Ends"
# It will be deleted while uninstalling GZip Ninja Speed plugin
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/otf .otf #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/eot .eot #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/woff .woff #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType image/x-icon .ico #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType image/png .png #GZip Ninja Speed
# GZip Ninja Speed -- Ends here
# GZip Ninja Speed -- Starts here
# Do not write anything between "GZip Ninja Speed -- Starts" and "GZip Ninja Speed -- Ends"
# It will be deleted while uninstalling GZip Ninja Speed plugin
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript #GZip Ninja Speed
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/otf .otf #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/eot .eot #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType x-font/woff .woff #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType image/x-icon .ico #GZip Ninja Speed
AddType image/png .png #GZip Ninja Speed
# GZip Ninja Speed -- Ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using WP Super Cache to redirect people to static HTML files from your HT Access.
If there's a problem with that it could be causing your speed issues.

The default Wordpress HT Access looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

You could try removing everything begin BEGIN WPSuperCache and END WPSuperCache

Comment: I added supercache in order to avoid 15 sec page load time,this reduced it to 12 seconds,with added plugins.The site is being directed to someone's home page un connected to my site. I did vist the xrummer site ;) so should have expected something,the Russian should say thank you for visiting not hit my site lol

Comment: They probably are using PHP to redirect away from your site then not HT Access.